# Very Naughty exception -Managed code called FailFast, saying

Tags: wpf, exception

In my WPF application,i am getting below exception when i run my PC with Tablet PC on Mode

```
CLR: Managed code called FailFast, saying " 
Unrecoverable system error.
```

Any body have any idea on this? Why this exception popsup?

Comment: Why don't you post the related code and stack trace of the exception?

Comment: It happens when i run my application in client side (it is a huge code base) I got only above log file. The application became crashed even without loging any message

Comment: Have you tried using an [exception handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx) and try to get more informations from there? currently its not much we can help you with.

Comment: NO, I will handle this.. thank you.

Comment: That doesn't work.  FailFast is much what it says, it is *fast*.  No exception is raised, instant crash to the desktop.  It is supposed to be able to generate a minidump, how to configure the machine to get one is however a well-kept secret.  Having one on a tablet PC certainly doesn't help.